# Read mp3 Popularimeter in ID3.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, id3

Anyone know how to get the value of the POPM frame ([Popularimeter](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#sec4.18) ID3 tag) in [ID3.NET](http://id3.codeplex.com/)?

If it is not possible, is there any other easy way to read the Popularimeter of mp3 files in C# .NET?

Comment: Do you ask how to read the frame "POPM" or what are the possible values for ½, 1, 1½, 2, 2½ etc?

Comment: The first one (how to get the value of the POPM frame). Thanks for asking :)

Comment: It is not currently supported and will be treated as an UnknownFrame. You can always add support for it and provide a patch to the project maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible with `ID3.NET` you can try to use `Taglib` Sharp.